# What's the replacement of `./gradlew packForXcode` in latest KMM with Cocoapod?

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I'm working as per the KMM tutorial in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/integrate-in-existing-app.htm. When I reach the the step `./gradlew packForXcode`, it will fail with

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'packForXcode' not found in root project 'Simple Login'.
```

I suspect the reason is the old KMM has `packForXcxode` for it's iOS framework.
[image]

However, the new one is now with Cocoapod instead
[image]

What's the equivalent `./gradlew packForXcode` for KMM with Cocoapod

(FYI, the KMM version I use is 0.2.5(202-1.5.10-834-IJ)-3 Plugin)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`packForXcode` has been removed from the latest plugin versions, you could use this snippet:

```
val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION") ?: "DEBUG"
    val target = if(System.getenv("SDK_NAME").orEmpty().startsWith("macosx")) "macOS" else "ios"
    val framework =
        kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(target).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
```

(It might need some tweaks for your project)